onClick triggering page refresh and setting page params from useParams hook as 'undefined'
I have an interesting problem. I have a product page and an 'add item' button. When the button is clicked the product id will be updated in the 'items' array state variable. I'm getting the product id from the url params using 'useParams' hook.
Now here's the thing. I put log statements at different steps in my code and found that when I navigate FROM the home page TO the product page, the page url param i.e., product id is correctly getting stored and logged.
But when I click the 'add item' button, it seems to immediately re-render the page and then sets the url param from the useParams hook - which was previously holding the proper page id - as 'undefined', which then is subsequently updating to the 'items' state variable as 'undefined'.
Here's the code:
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from 'react';


function AddToCart() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log(id);

  function addItem() {
    setItems([...items, id]);
  }

  console.log(items);

    return ( 
        <div className='add-to-cart'>
          <button className='add-btn' onClick={() => addItem()}>Add Item</button>
          {/* <Link to={`cart/${items}`}><FontAwesomeIcon className='cart-btn' icon={faBasketShopping} size='3x' /></Link> */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddToCart;

Page route:
 function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <MenuTitle/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path='/item_page/:id' element={<Item/>}/>
          {/* <Route path='/cart/:id' element={<Cart/>}/> */}
        </Routes>
      <AddToCart/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I looked up on Google and tried the e.preventDefault() method inside the function block but that didn't work either. How can I solve this?
Adding screen snips of console before and after clicking the button

The useParams hook only reads the URL path, it doesn't set anything. Please [edit] to show your router/routing setup so we can see if id is even a defined route path parameter. Is AddToCart being rendered within a form element? Please include a complete [mcve].

@DrewReese Yes sir. Id is a defined route. In the first screen snip you can see id: 2 is getting logged. If I didn't define it wouldn't work even initially. It is only after the button click - page refresh, that it is setting to undefined.

Edited to add page route

AddToCart isn't rendered on a route, so it would make sense that the useParams would return undefined values.

@DrewReese Ok. I found the culprit. Basically I'm rendering this AddToCart component twice on the page. One is sticky and the other one is way at the bottom of the page when i scroll down. removed the duplicate and it is now working as expected. Answering my question with screen snip.

So I found out that I was rendering this AddToCart component in two different places mistakenly. One in the App.js file with the intention to make it render on all pages. The other on the product page which is actually holding the context of the current page route. Removed the former duplicate from the App.js which leaves us with the actual button and it is now working as expected.
